# format int to phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way I can format for example: 0000000000 into (000)000-0000? I'm returning a listbox which holds a collection of phone number which arent formated yet. What I would like is format it. This is what I have in the View:

```
<%= Html.ListBox("phoneList")%>
```

and from the controller:

```
ViewData["phoneList"] = new SelectList(phoneList);
```

**Edit**

```
$('#phoneList').each(function() {
                var phoneNumber = $(this).text();
                var formatPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1)$2-$3');
                alert(formatPhoneNumber);
            });
```

how would I assign this back to show in the ListBox?

Comment: This will only work for US style phone numbers. UK & other European countries format their numbers differently.

Comment: hersh - Just saw your comment before it disappeared, so I assume you figured it out. I don't know exactly what type of element you have, but I imagine if you got the original value with `$(this).text()`, you should be able to assign the new value the same way. `$(this).text(formatPhoneNumber)`

Comment: patrick - yes, I figured it out and thanks for getting back at me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're saying that you want to do it on the client side, then given the phone number in a variable, you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HZbXv/

```
var str = "0000000000";

var res = '(' + str.substr(0,3) + ')' + str.substr(3,3) + '-' + str.substr(6);

alert(res);
```

or this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HZbXv/1/

```
var str = "0000000000";

var res = str.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '($1)$2-$3');

alert(res);
```

---

**EDIT:**

As noted by *@Nick Craver* The second version can be shortened up with:

```
var res = str.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1)$2-$3');
```

Comment: +1 - Just a note you can slim it down a bit further: `str.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1)$2-$3');`

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this. Can use a simple if statement if you are going to deal with multiple numbers.

```
    YourVariable = YourVariable.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "+$1 ($2)-$3-$4");
```

Displays: +1 (800)-555-5555

```
    YourVariable = YourVariable.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1)-$2-$3");
```

Displays (555)-555-5555

If statement (my own code):

```
if (form.FaxNumber.length = 11){
    form.FaxNumber.value = form.FaxNumber.value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "+$1 ($2)-$3-$4");
}
if (form.FaxNumber.length = 10){
    form.FaxNumber.value = form.FaxNumber.value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1)-$2-$3");
}
```