# Pattern matching in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have strings(phone numbers) like this:

```
1112223333
1234567890
```

And I want to convert these like this:

```
(111)222-3333
(123)456-7890
```

How to do this is jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579479/format-int-to-phone-number

Comment: Heh, you're right... but writing regular expressions is just so much fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No jquery needed, just javascript regular expressions:

```
var aNumber = '1112223333';
var aPhoneNumber = aNumber.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '($1)$2-$3');
```

By the way, I'm assuming numbers are always of the form '(xxx)xxx-xxxx', 3-3-4 numbers.

Comment: Both have the same pattern so "come first get first" policy is applied.

Comment: @Awan Sort of, mine allows for an arbitrary length of last digits. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var phone = '1234567890';

phone.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, '($1)$2-$3'); // (123)456-7890
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qatce/).

If you want to match that length exactly, use a `{4}` quantifier in place of the last `+`.