# How to format a US tel number using a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Using `someStringArray.indexOf()` logic in a `forEach` loop is getting tripped up when an element has duplicate numbers.

I'm trying to take a US tel number and format as `(xxx)xxx-xxxx` using the 10 digit number initially as a string. Then converting to an array so I can loop through it and format it.

```
"use strict";

let tel = 5149100499;
let telStr = tel.toString();
let ntel = telStr.split('');

ntel.forEach(char => {
  let d = ntel.indexOf(char);
  if(ntel.indexOf(char) === 0) {
      ntel.splice(d,0,"(");
  }else if(ntel.indexOf(char) === 4){
      ntel.splice(d,0,")");
  }else if(ntel.indexOf(char, 7) === 9){
      ntel.splice(d,0,"-");
  }

});

let ntelStr = ntel.join('');

  console.log(ntelStr);
```

Ideally the output should be: 
`ntelStr = (514)910-0499`

Comment: Hello @Brubklyn. Refer this link for multiple solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579479/format-int-to-phone-number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string#replace` to convert the telephone number to the desired format.

```js
"use strict";

let tel = 5149100499,
    result = tel.toString().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/,'($1)$2-$3');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was thinking when I researched RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tel = 5149100499;
var s = tel.toString();
s = `(${s.substring(0, 3)})${s.substring(3,6)}-${s.substring(6,10)}`
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was anticipating a regEx solution, but this will work too!